# Azure when does wad-control-container gets populated

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I uploaded the azure web application with custom dianostics.wadcfg and also included the onstart() function to transfer logs to azure storage on schedule basis.

However, the wad-control-container is always empty. I would have thought that this should include the xml configuration for given deployment ID.

Could someone please suggest on what scenarios this occurs?

Comment: Diagnostics starts before the onstart event so that it can capture errors in the onstart event. It sounds like you have diagnostics configured wrong. can you post your config file for diagnostics?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today and the problem was that I used HTTP to connect to storage instead of HTTPS. Might be it.